# I have trouble exporting data grid view to Excel

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, export

I'm trying to create an app that queries an SQL data base and then export the grid view on button click to excel for importing to our payroll system. If I take out the following line of code the the only error I get is `Payroll.Form1.Submit_Click(object, System.EventArgs)` must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial" IF i put the body back in then I get 22 errors. can some one point me in the right direction? My full code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace Payroll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fillToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1TableAdapter.Fill(this.fabTrolMRPDataSet.MIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1, new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(fromdateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))), new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(todateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);
    }


    DataTableToExcel();
    {
        public void DataTableToExcel()
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                // see the excel sheet behind the program
                app.Visible = true;
                // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
                // store its reference to worksheet
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                // changing the name of active sheet
                worksheet.Name = "Employees";
                // storing header part in Excel
                for (int i = 1; i < mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }

                // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
                for (int i = 0; i <= mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        string values = string.Empty;
                        values = mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = values;
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Release the resources
                app.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
                app = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is how your code is, then you should be getting some compilation errors! your call to `DataTableToExcel` is out of scope. And the method declaration is in the namespace scope. You should move it inside the form class

Comment: why did you declare method DataTableToExcel() outside any class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a method declaration, so it MUST have a body

Change `private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);` and since its an event handler it should be **protected** (accessable from designer)

to

```
 protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //call your code to export to excel
}
```

---

**Complete code**

```
namespace Payroll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fillToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1TableAdapter.Fill(this.fabTrolMRPDataSet.MIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1, new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(fromdateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))), new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(todateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTableToExcel();
        }

        public void DataTableToExcel()
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            try
            {

                // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                // see the excel sheet behind the program
                app.Visible = true;
                // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
                // store its reference to worksheet
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                // changing the name of active sheet
                worksheet.Name = "Employees";
                // storing header part in Excel
                for (int i = 1; i < mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }

                // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
                for (int i = 0; i <= mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        string values = string.Empty;
                        values = mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = values;
                    }

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Release the resources
                app.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
                app = null;


            }

      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, however still have the same error tried abstract, extern and partial as well.

Comment: @MichaelTerrian check my edit. You had the scope/brackets messed up

Comment: Tried it and get lots of errors. Changed private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e); to protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e); same result.

Comment: @MichaelTerrian my bad.. I just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to export dataGrid view that is a little more efficient. Full code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Payroll
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fillToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1TableAdapter.Fill(this.fabTrolMRPDataSet.MIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1, new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(fromdateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))), new System.Nullable<System.DateTime>(((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(todateToolStripTextBox.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))));
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


            {

                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


                xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                int i = 0;
                int j = 0;

                for (i = 0; i <= mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j <= mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                    {
                        DataGridViewCell cell = mIS_FTTIMECARTSQL1DataGridView[j, i];
                        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;


                    }

                }

                xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Time.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

                releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
                releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
                releaseObject(xlApp);

                MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\Time.xls");
            }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

   }
}
```